# Sequelize belongsToMany ignores additional attributes in join table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models: **Article** and **DescriptionFragment** in a  *BelongsToMany* association through a join table **Descriptions**, which in turn *BelongsTo* another model **Category** and also has an attribute "sequence", all defined as follows:

**Article** model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'uid'
    },
    articleNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(8),
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'article_number',
      unique: true
    },
  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  Article.associate = function (models) {
    Article.belongsToMany(models.DescriptionFragment, {
      through: 'Descriptions',
      as: 'articleWithDescriptionFragment',
      otherKey: {
        name: 'descriptionFragmentId',
        field: 'description_fragment_id'
      },
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'articleId',
        field: 'article_id'
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Article;
};
```

**DescriptionFragment** model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const DescriptionFragment = sequelize.define('DescriptionFragment', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'uid'
    }
  }, {
    charset: 'utf8',
    dialectOptions: {
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    },
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
  });
  DescriptionFragment.associate = function (models) {
    DescriptionFragment.belongsToMany(models.Article, {
      through: 'Descriptions',
      as: 'descriptionFragmentForArticle',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'descriptionFragmentId',
        field: 'description_fragment_id'
      },
      otherKey: {
        name: 'articleId',
        field: 'article_id'
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return DescriptionFragment;
};
```

**Description** model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Description = sequelize.define('Description', {
    sequence: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    charset: 'utf8',
    dialectOptions: {
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    },
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
  });
  Description.associate = function (models) {
    Description.belongsTo(models.Category, {
      as: 'categoryDescription',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'categoryId',
        field: 'category_id'
      },
      targetKey: 'uid',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Description;
};
```

**Category** model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'uid'
    }
  }, {
    charset: 'utf8',
    dialectOptions: {
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
    },
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
  });
  Category.associate = function (models) {
    Category.hasMany(models.Description, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'categoryId',
        field: 'category_id'
      },
      sourceKey: 'uid',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Category;
};
```

My problem comes when I try to associate a **DescriptionFragment** to an **Article**. I'm using the following code:

```
let addedArticle = await Article.create(newArticle);

addedArticle.addArticleWithDescriptionFragment(descFrag, {
    through: {
      categoryId: catId,
      sequence: index
    }
  });
```

where *descFrag* is an instance of the **DescriptionFragment** model, and *catId* and *index* are integers.

When that code is run, sequelize creates the **Article** instance *addedArticle*, but then when trying to associate it to **DescriptionFragment** it just ignores what is in the *through* option. The SQL generated is, for example:

```sql
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "devdb"."Descriptions" ("created_at","updated_at","article_id","description_fragment_id") VALUES ('2019-02-07 15:11:15.376 +00:00','2019-02-07 15:11:15.376 +00:00',95,5);
```

As far as I could find in the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html), the syntax I'm using is correct, and the association is created in the **Descriptions** table, just with `null` for *sequence* and *category_id*.

I'm using sequelize v4.38.1 and the database is Postgres.

I can't spot where is the error and all similar issues I have found so far were just using in sequelize v4 the old syntax for v3.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

For now I'm using the following workaround:

```js
await addedArticle.addArticleWithDescriptionFragment(descFrag);
let newDesc = await models.Description.find({
  where: { articleId: addedArticle.uid, descriptionFragmentId: descFrag.uid }
});
await newDesc.update({ categoryId: catId, sequence: index });
```

which correctly sets the desired columns:

```sql
Executing (default): UPDATE "techred_dev"."Descriptions" SET "category_id"=2,"sequence"=0,"updated_at"='2019-02-08 09:21:20.216 +00:00' WHERE "article_id" = 104 AND "description_fragment_id" = 6
```

Of course for this to work I had to update my **Description** model explicitly adding the *articleId* and *descriptionFragmentId* columns:

```js
articleId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  references: {
    model: 'Articles',
    key: 'uid'
  },
  primaryKey: true,
  field: 'article_id'
},
descriptionFragmentId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  references: {
    model: 'DescriptionFragments',
    key: 'uid'
  },
  primaryKey: true,
  field: 'description_fragment_id'
},
```

Still, the 'through' option in the 'add' method does not work and I have no clue why.